# lambda function returning false

Tags: python, lambda, pyqt

I have a python program in pyqt with a button with the follwoing:

```
this=[1,k]   
button.clicked.connect(lambda x=this:self.testFunction(str(x)))
```

When I press the button I get `testFunction(False)` rather `testFunction(str([1,k]))`.  Any ideas why?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the problem remain if you change `this` to, say, `these` on both lines? (This will either fix the problem or disprove the hypothesis that something is setting `this` to `False` between the first line and the second.)

Comment: I got it working with the following:


self.connect(button,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),lambda x=this:self.testFunction(str(x)))

Comment: I've never used qt, but here's my guess: lambdas you use for event binding ought to have `event` for a first argument: `button.clicked.connect(lambda event, x=this: self.testFunction(str(x)))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that you are misinterpretting how `lambda` works. Lambda returns an anonymous function with the definition you give it. By saying `lambda x=this:` you are saying if the call to this function doesn't have an `x` argument default to use this instead.

Observe:

```
l = lambda x=3: x*2
print l(10)  # Prints 20
print l()    # Prints 6
```

If we check the documentation for [`QPushButton.clicked()` (inherited from QAbstractButton)](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractbutton.html#clicked), we see that it fires with a boolean argument.

So in this line:

```
button.clicked.connect(lambda x=this:self.testFunction(str(x)))
```

The lambda function *always* gets passed an argument, which is passed from `QPushButton.clicked()` and will be either `True` or `False`. Hence the default of `this` is never used. As an alternate you could use:

```
button.clicked.connect(lambda x:self.testFunction(str(this)))
```

But that isn't probably what you want, as it will always pass the string variant of the array this to the function. On the other hand this:

```
button.clicked.connect(lambda x:self.testFunction(str(this[x])))
```

Will pass the string casting of their `1` or `k` depending on whether the passed argument is `True` or `False`.

Comment: One item missing from this (very useful) answer: you can completely ignore the boolean value using: `button.clicked.connect(lambda ignore, x = this : self.testFunction(str(x)))`. The boolean value gets assigned to `ignore` (and is ignored) and `x` (i.e., `this`) is properly used as the argument of the function.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem but the lambda didn't accept the ignore nor checked and I was getting an error that the lambda was missing a positional argument. I don't know if this is the right thing, but it worked for me. I fixed by assigning
`checked=True`

```
button.clicked.connect(lambda checked=True, x=this:self.testFunction(str(x)))
```

Comment: This just worked for me. Thank you so much!