# PySide2/PyQt5 Problem with connecting multiple buttons and image labels properly with respective timers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside2

I have 5 QGroupboxes, all having a QLabel for video display and a corresponding "View" QPushButton.
Whenever a button is clicked, the click is connected to a function, which accepts a timer as argument and starts it and starts another function as a thread which also accepts the same timer and stops it at the end.
I have created arrays for all objects first and then done all connections with timers/buttons/groupbox layout etc in a loop.

The problem I am facing is whenever I click a button, the same display lable gets activated and shows the video, rather than the respective lable I want to start with the passed timer.

So, I would like to know where I am going wrong or what is some other way to do it (or something better, I am new to PyQt)

This is the function for the creation of all the things, I can try to post a full reproducible code if anyone wants.

```
def create_addition_tab(self, num=5):
        self.add_multiple_groupbox = QGroupBox("Add multiple")

        label_add_id = QLabel("ID")
        text_edit_add_id = QLineEdit()
        label_add_id.setBuddy(text_edit_add_id)

        pushbutton_view = QPushButton("View")
        pushbutton_add = QPushButton("Capture")

        titles = ['Front','Right', 'Left', 'Up', 'Down']

        timers = [QTimer() for i in range(num)]
        image_labels = [QLabel() for i in range(num)]
        addition_boxes = [QGroupBox(titles[i]) for i in range(num)]
        push_buttons = [QPushButton("View") for i in range(num)]
        add_box_layouts = [QGridLayout() for i in range(num)]

        for ind in range(num):
            image_labels[ind].setPixmap(self.defaultpixmap.scaled(100, 100, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation))
            timers[ind].timeout.connect(lambda: self.add_image_tab(timers[ind],image_labels[ind]))
            push_buttons[ind].clicked.connect(lambda: self.add_image_to_tab(timers[ind]))

            add_box_layouts[ind].addWidget(image_labels[ind],0,0)
            add_box_layouts[ind].addWidget(push_buttons[ind],1,0)
            addition_boxes[ind].setLayout(add_box_layouts[ind])

        add_multiple_groupbox_layout = QGridLayout()
        add_multiple_groupbox_layout.addWidget(label_add_id, 0, 0)
        add_multiple_groupbox_layout.addWidget(text_edit_add_id, 0, 1)

        for idx,i in enumerate(addition_boxes):
            add_multiple_groupbox_layout.addWidget(i,1+(idx)//2,idx%2)

        add_multiple_groupbox_layout.addWidget(pushbutton_add)
        self.add_multiple_groupbox.setLayout(add_multiple_groupbox_layout)
```

Comment: change to`push_buttons[ind].clicked.connect(lambda checked, timer=timers[ind]: self.add_image_to_tab(timer))`

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks, I never thought it might be because of my wrong usage of lambda, but can you also inform me why I need the `checked` in lambda (i had to use a parameter set to any value along with timer otherwise the timer went as a bool), this didn't happen for the line above it `timers[i].timeout.connect(lambda timer=timers[i],image_label=image_labels[i]: self.add_image_tab(timer,image_label))`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368468/pyqt5-button-lambda-variable-becomes-boolean